# Filtering augmented diffs by type of tag change

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I want to find all deletions of a certain tag.  I'm trying to do this:

```
[timeout:500][adiff:"2023-09-15T00:00:00Z","2023-09-18T00:00:00Z"];
node["name:ru"]({{bbox}});
(._;>;);
out meta skel body;
```

But this query shows all actions with tags. Is it possible to search for a specific action on a tag, such as deleting it?